# Opening a doc/dox/xsl/xslx/txt file using localhost http on Android

Tags: android, kotlin, url, android-intent, uri

We want to open a file by using an internal HTTP service.
The idea is that the app will send an HTTP request to localhost and our service will catch it and parse the rest of the URI and do something.

We succeed to read JPEG/Video/PDF but docs seem not to be supported.

We are using Intent and Android URI and start the Intent but the Application does not lunch the app chooser and nothing happen.

The mime is correct (when we try to open the file using the `file` scheme the file opened.

Here is our code:

```
var uriString: String = "http://localhost:12345/<file path>.doc"
val uRI = Uri.parse(uriString)
val mime: String = getMimeType(uriString)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.setDataAndType(uRI, mime)
resultForActivityLauncher.launch(intent)
```

What we are doing wrong/missing, or is there any workaround?

Thanks ahead

Comment: `will send an HTTP request to localhost ` Localhost? Every device is its own localhost. So your Android device is localhost. Moreover: are you with your Android device in town? Or where?

Comment: `We succeed to read JPEG/Video/PDF` I doubt that. Not with that code from an Android device. Not with 'localhost'.

Comment: Let me clarify, the app sends an URI to the external app and the app use the URI to open a file. URI has scheme and destination. We develop a http listener service that listen on the localhost IP and a specific port, So the external app sends a http query (according to the URI provided) we catch this query and do what we do with the data. What I just described worked with pdf but when we trying to open doc the external app does not sends the http query from the URI. It works only if the scheme is "file"

Comment: What I want to achieve is when I provide an URI with http scheme and doc extension, my app will popup the chooser view and when I will choose the doc reader app (ms word) the external app will use the URI and my app will provide the data of the file and the external app wouldn't have a direct access to the file

Comment: If you use ACTION_VIEW to display a .doc file then does the chooser come up? Are doc readers installed on device?  Also is mime type correct by getMimeType()?

Comment: So the ms word app can read content from http urls i understand?

Comment: If the user always has to choose the ms word app you could directly open ms word with getLaunchIntentForPackage(). Any differences for Android versions?

Comment: But your only problem at the moment is that ACTION_VIEW does pop up nothing... ?

Comment: The mime is fine, and the chooser comes up only of the URI contains 'file' scheme. If the scheme is 'http' nothing happen

Comment: But you said it works for jpg and pdf and so.

Comment: @blackapps exactly my point, for jpeg,mkv,mp4,pdf it is working, but when I'm doing the same for doc,docx,txt,xls,xlsx,etc is doesn't work.
You can try to open a txt file using an HTTP uri scheme and see what's happening, I think that it's related to opening a "txt" file, the question is what is the difference in Android URI internal handling.

Comment: Please tell your 'fine' mime type as for Java i wanna try your intent.

Comment: @blackapps I took the mime from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types

Comment: Nothing happens? Well here i got an ActivityNotFoundException for application/msword. Which was not surprising as i have no such apps.

Comment: Try it with txt

Comment: Please be more presice.